# C# scripting API does not load assembly

Tags: c#, scripting

I tried to write a .net core console program to use the C# scripting API to run a linq statement, but I keep getting error saying

'System.Linq, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Native image cannot be loaded multiple times.

Here is my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default;

                //Add reference to mscorlib
                var mscorlib = typeof(System.Object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                var systemCore = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddReferences(mscorlib, systemCore);

                //Add namespaces
                scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddImports("System");
                scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddImports("System.Linq");
                scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddImports("System.Collections.Generic");

                var state = CSharpScript.RunAsync(@"var x = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};", scriptOptions).Result;
                state = state.ContinueWithAsync("var y = x.Take(3).ToList();").Result;

                var y = state.Variables[1];
                var yList = (List<int>)y.Value;
                foreach(var val in yList)
                {
                Console.Write(val + " "); // Prints 1 2 3
                }
            }
            catch (CompilationErrorException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Diagnostics));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting": "2.0.0-rc2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": ["dnxcore50", "net452"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems to be a dependency conflict between `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting` and `Microsoft.NETCore.App` targeting different versions of the `System` dlls, until those are aligned, it looks like you can use the `InteractiveAssemblyLoader` to tell the `CSharpScript` compiler to load the version of the dependencies that the app actually provides.

```cs
    var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default;

    // Add reference to mscorlib
    var mscorlib = typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var systemCore = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

    var references = new[] { mscorlib, systemCore };
    scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddReferences(references);

    List<int> yList;
    using (var interactiveLoader = new InteractiveAssemblyLoader())
    {
        foreach (var reference in references)
        {
            interactiveLoader.RegisterDependency(reference);
        }

        // Add namespaces
        scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddImports("System");
        scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddImports("System.Linq");
        scriptOptions = scriptOptions.AddImports("System.Collections.Generic");

        // Initialize script with custom interactive assembly loader
        var script = CSharpScript.Create(@"", scriptOptions, null, interactiveLoader);
        var state = script.RunAsync().Result;

        state = state.ContinueWithAsync(@"var x = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};").Result;
        state = state.ContinueWithAsync("var y = x.Take(3).ToList();").Result;

        var y = state.Variables[1];
        yList = (List<int>)y.Value;
    }

    foreach (var val in yList)
    {
        Console.Write(val + " "); // Prints 1 2 3
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: Wow, it works~ Thank you very much. p.s. InteractiveAssemblyLoader is disposable, so you may want to update this answer with using.