# C# - how to use dependencies with rosyln (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Csharp.Scripting)

Tags: c#

So I'm making a program in C# that allows users to add a custom script from a file called **custom.cs**, I am using **rosyln** / **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Csharp.Scripting** to execute the code from above **.cs** file, I'm wondering on how I would make dependencies from inside the main exe work in the **custom.cs**

Comment: I tink that is done in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41356621/724039

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure to take a look.